# Table Row Acordeon

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Tengo una tabla donde muestro información sobre reserva de mesas de un restaurante.

Quisiera que en dispositivos móviles cada reserva se vea en acordeón.

De momento tengo hecho que al cambiar de vista se reagrupen los datos de la reserva, solo me quedaría que al pulsar encima del número de reserva se visualice el resto de los datos.

Adjunto código de la tabla y del `css` que modifica la tabla en modo móvil y unas imágenes de lo que tengo en vista pc y móvil.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .table_reserves {
    border: 0;
  }
  .table_reserves caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .table_reserves thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  .table_reserves tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  .table_reserves td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .table_reserves .acordeon-header {
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .table_reserves td::before {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaPersonas" class="table_reserves table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:100%">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>Reserva</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Cognom</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Telefon</th>
      <th>Persones</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Accions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php                            
      foreach($data as $dat) {  
        //canviar format de la data a Dia-Mes-Any
        $data_correcta = $data_correcta = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dat['data']));
    ?>
    <tr>
      <input type="radio" name="toggle" class="accordion-toggle" checked />
      <td claass="acordeon-header">
        <?php echo $dat['id'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $dat['nom'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $dat['apellidos'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $dat['email'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $dat['telefon'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $dat['persones'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $data_correcta ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $dat['hora'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!--<div class='text-center'>
          <div class='btn-group'>
            <form action="../pdf/print.php" method="post">
              <!--Per captar el id de la reserva i despres eviar-ho a la pagina per editar la reserva en type hidden per a no voreu-->
              <!--<input type="hidden" name="id_imprimir" id="id_imprimir" value="<?php echo $dat['id'] ?>">
              <button type="submit" name="imprimir" id="imprimir" class='btn btn-success borde_rodo_botons borde_rodo_btn_imp'>Imprimir</button>
            </form>
            <button type="submit" id="btnEditar" class='btn btn-primary btnEditar borde_rodo_botons'>Editar</button>
            <button type="submit" class='btn btn-danger btnBorrar'>Borrar</button>
          </div>
       </div>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php}?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La verdad no entiendo mucho el problema, ¿podrías explicar un poco mejor cual es la falla?

Comment: Yo solo quiero que con este codigo, hacer la table un acordeon de cada linea (que es una reserva) desde el numero de reserva que es el 470 (un ejemplo).

Comment: Puedes apoyarte en `datatables`. La librería te proporciona herramientas para que tus tablas se comporten tal como lo necesitas. [aquí un ejemplo](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/option.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te mencioné en el comentario, puedes apoyarte en `datatables`. Es una librería que te ahorra mucho trabajo al maquetar tablas como las necesites.

Este es solo un ejemplo con los datos que facilitas en las imágenes, pero debes adaptarlo a tu proyecto. Puedes [ver el ejemplo completo en la documentación oficial](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/default.html).

*Ejecuta el snippet en pantalla completa y usa las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador para que veas el comportamiento en modo responsivo.*

```js
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  responsive: true
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Reserva</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Cognom</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Telefon</th>
      <th>Persones</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Accions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>470</td>
      <td>Joel</td>
      <td>1234</td>
      <td>joel@gmail.com</td>
      <td>612122122</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>2023-05-21</td>
      <td>12:30</td>
      <td>Editar - Borrar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>471</td>
      <td>Alfredo</td>
      <td>Vidal</td>
      <td>alfredo@gmail.com</td>
      <td>676423102</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>2023-05-21</td>
      <td>13:30</td>
      <td>Editar - Borrar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```